# What's the difference between Response.WriteAsync and returning a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hi I was wandering if someone can explain to me the difference between these two methods for returning data from a controller.
Is there an advantage or reason for using on method over the other?

I am guessing that the returning function just calls `Response.WriteAsync` further down the line but I am not sure.

Using postman both methods return the exact same response, so I was just curious about the two options, is there a reason for using one over the other or just personal preference.

Between Response.WriteAsync:

```
[HttpGet("Fetch_WriteAsync")]
public async Task Fetch_AsyncWrite()
{
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = "my_fetched_data" }));
}
```

and just returning:

```
[HttpGet("Fetch_Return")]
public async Task<string> Fetch_Return()
{
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = "my_fetched_data" }));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically there is a difference regarding how your code is executed under the hood. In the first case, in which you have this

```
await HttpContext.Response
                 .WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
                  { 
                      data = "my_fetched_data" 
                  }));
```

an ASP.NET thread would be used to execute your code.

While in the second case, in which you have this

```
return await Task.Factory
                 .StartNew(()=>JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
                 { 
                     data = "my_fetched_data" 
                 }));
```

a thread pool thread would be used.

As it is stated [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/dont-use-the-threadpool-in-aspnet):

> You can use the ThreadPool in exactly the same way in ASP.NET and it
>   works just as you would expect. **The problem is** not in the ThreadPool
>   itself but in what else ASP.NET uses it for at the same time. ASP.NET
>   is multi-threaded by design and it uses the ThreadPool to serve pages
>   and content mapped to the ASP.NET ISAPI filter.
>
> **If you also use the ThreadPool, then ASP.NET has fewer threads to**
>   **utilize and requests are put on hold until the pool returns a free**
>   **thread**. This might not be a problem for a low traffic site, but more
>   popular sites can get into trouble. Low traffic sites can get into
>   trouble if they use the ThreadPool a lot.

That being said, I would opt for the first solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is the answer the question but it isn't the question I was asking (badly worded question sorry). It did open another interesting chain of thought. Although I was more curious as to writing directly to the response vs returning the string.

Comment: @Heinrich You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped.