# Equivalent of HttpServerUtility.Execute in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In .Net 4.8 I can use Server.Execute(String, TextWriter) to execute a different page on my ASP.Net site and return the results of that page.  Any idea how to do that in .NET Core?

I cannot find a compatible method in .NET Core.

Comment: You can use `Response.WriteAsync` see this question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872011/whats-the-difference-between-response-writeasync-and-returning-a-string

Comment: See also Configuring .NET Core request processing pipeline https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/01/configure-aspnet-core-request.html

Answer (score 0):

> In .Net 4.8 I can use Server.Execute(String, TextWriter) to execute a
> different page on my ASP.Net site and return the results of that page.
> Any idea how to do that in .NET Core?

This looks similar to the function of a partial view.

For example, we can create a partial view (_pvTestView.cshtml) in the MVC application Shared folder.

[image]

the partial view code like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.Name != null)
{ 
    <h1>Hello @ViewBag.Name , This is the partial view </h1>
}
@if (ViewBag.UserName != null)
{ 
    <h1>Hello @ViewBag.UserName , This is the partial view </h1>
}
```

Then in the controller: we can use the ICompositeViewEngine to render the partial view and get the view content, after that you can return it to the main page.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        //execute the partial view and transfer parameter.
        var returndata = await ExecutePageAsync("_pvTestView", "Dillion");
        
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<string> ExecutePageAsync(string viewName, string username)
    {
        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, false);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            // Handle the case where the view cannot be found
            return null;
        }


        ViewBag.UserName = username;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                ControllerContext,
                viewEngineResult.View,
                ViewData,
                TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewEngineResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And, if you want to directly render the partial view in the main page, you can use the `@Html.Partial()` attribute to render the view page:

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.Partial("_pvTestView", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData){{ "Name", "Tom" }})
```

The test screenshot as below:

[image]

[image]

More detail information, see [Partial views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0)